# How to treat block (IV) in glm?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, logistic-curve, variable

I have a word learning experiment in which I am measuring `accuracy` on a 2AFC task. So, my DV is binary (1=correct, 0=incorrect). As IVs I have `condition` (with two levels: reliable and unreliable) and `block` (ordinal? with four levels: 1, 2, 3, and 4). My questions are about the latter IV and its nature.

Since the learning curve observed across blocks is like the one you observe below (thus, not linear): [image]

1) How should I treat block: as factor and do orthogonal contrasts (which exactly?), or treat it as a numerical variable? Doing the former (I assume) would respect the nature of the variable. However, I have asked around colleagues who work on similar designs and treat this variable as numerical.

2) If numerical, should I center it (`scale(block, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)`) or not? What would I be doing exactly if I do center it? When asking to the same colleagues, I get mixed answers: some do center it (with block = 4), others do not (with block = 8).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! Here's what I think:

1. The block numbers you are using are just labels (i.e., 1 denotes the first block, 2 denotes the second block, etc.), though the labels do not follow a natural ordering (e.g., we can't claim that block 2 is "better" than block 1; we can't claim that block 2 is "twice as good as" block 1).
2. Because of the lack of a natural ordering, it makes sense to treat block as a factor in R. (By default, when you create a factor in R with the factor() command, it will be unordered.)
3. When you introduce block and condition as (unordered) factors in your model, you can use a deviation coding scheme for each factor or a dummy variable coding scheme, for example. The appropriate scheme will depend on what type of effects you are really interested in, as explained for instance here: http://www.mypolyuweb.hk/~sjpolit/coding_schemes.html.